# Finding and Selecting Duplicates Trouble Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, duplicates

So I have a code that is supposed to change the font of my selection to red. I have pulled two tables from a SQL database and would like to select two columns from these tables and highlight all duplicates. However, the below code only highlights the two columns and does not make any font changes. The font  does actually change when I, say delete any duplicate value from D11 to D2000 (or from M11:M200) and rewrite that value. How can I make it so that the font change occurs automatically?

```
Sub Duplicates()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Application.Union(Range("Sheet1!D11:D2000"), Range("Sheet1!M11:M200"))
Rng.Select
With Selection 
    .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues 
    .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority 
    .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
End With 

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font 
    .Bold = True
    .Color = -16776961 
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it appears to work. Maybe you need to refresh the condition after your queries run? You might need to remove and re-add the condition.

I found a similar posting on this [thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/382099-conditional-formatting-does-not-refresh.html)

Looks like this code will delete the condition:

```
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
```

Comment: I've tried a few of the suggestions from the thread as well as your suggestion but it still will not work :(

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? I'm working with 2010. I created some data in a SQL 2012 table, setup two connections which have tables on the spreadsheet.  After running your code it formatted the duplicates and when I modified the data and refreshed the external data, it automatically updated the formatting. So I was not able to recreate your issue.

Comment: Im using 2010 as well and SQL 2008... yeah thats weird i can't figure out why it's not working

Comment: Do you have other conflicting conditional formats maybe? Maybe you can try it from a fresh workbook and see if that works? I've seen where the workbook can get corrupted or something else in a workbook causes a conflict.

Comment: I don't think so.. I did use a fresh workbook and tried just importing two random tables and running the code and that worked. however i then editted it to make it into my code and it failed again... would you care to take a look at my entire code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me too. Have you checked "EnableFormatConditionsCalculation" for your worksheet?

This was the solution pointed to;
[Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/conditional-formatting-does-not-update/08fed959-df7a-4e43-a0ae-a2aa5f587edd?page=2)

which leads to;

[Solution for the auto refresh problem with conditional formatting in Excel 2007](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10059693/conditional-formatting-in-2007.aspx)

but appears to be a problem for 2010 too? There are several other responses in these posts as well, you may find helpful.

Comment: I actually just tried that - using conditional formatting on the spreadsheet itself without VBA and i selected the entire table and went to conditional formatting - color scales - more rules - format when duplicates and then changed the color and hit okay. however, for some reason clear duplicates did not highlight - i made sure to check for spaces. any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: turns out there were trailing spaces that came out of nowhere. im retarded

Comment: Lol, that's great. My favorite is the hidden symbols like shift returns from pasting from other documents. Very frustrating. I TRIM(CLEAN()) everything now.